# How to know if css style was fully applied to dynamicly added content

Tags: jquery, html, css

The case:
Content is dynamically added to some div (using jquery). Content contains quite large amount of elements (say to 1000 divs).

Then I need to calculate correct dimensions of the elements (actually I need top position in px so I use jquery position() function). First I started to calculate right after content where added.

The problem is that SOMETIMES top position is calculated incorrectly I believe (and quite sure) that is because of css styles where not properly applied yet to that content.

I tried to solve this problem starting to callulate after some timeout (using setTimeout) after content was added. The more timeout I use (I tested from 20 to 500 ms) the more time browser has to apply styles and the less probability of incorrect calculation.

The problem is that this solution with timeout is not 100% reliable and safe, and I need to use quite large timeout to ensure process correctness and that may degrade overall performance of the process.

So I need to know when styles were fully applied and when I can start position calculations. What can you advice, is there any reliable way to do that?

Comment: do ALL your DOM manipulations inside `$(document).ready( function() { //Here } );` instead of using timeouts to wait for DOM elements to load. Also, all the new browsers support dev tools (Press F12), use that to target on a particular element and check its CSS properties.

Comment: CSS styles are applied immediately so the problem is elsewhere. If your process for calculating positions involves knowing the dimension of a div, just know that unless the dimension is defined in the CSS, you cannot extract the dimension of a non-visible item that hasn't been rendered on the screen.

Comment: should it be because some elements might have padding and you are probably getting their widths/heights by the css property instead of .outerHeight() or .outerWidth()

Comment: Are there images among the dynamic content?

Comment: @Alexander No Images. Just Text.

Comment: @w3jimmy I'm using jquery's position().

Comment: @frenchie content is put with jquery's html() as I know it is synchronous so all the content is present in DOM when calculation starts.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: no, I meant being present isn't enough; in order to calculate dimensions elements must be visible. I'm working on an app where the content is entirely generated at runtime with javascript and .html() and I've bumped into that problem myself too.

Comment: @frenchie what do mean by visible? (my content is in div that is not hidden, display: block) So when the content becomes "visible" after html(..) has been called?

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint the problem without some code to look at; I'm just sharing a similar experience I've had and that caused me some confusion as well. After .html() the content is rendered and if the container is visible then you can get dimensions no problem. Also, CSS styles are applied immediately so that can't be the cause your problem.

Comment: The content is visible. And I CAN get dimensions, but they are INCORRECT that means that in most cases I have say top = 190px, but sometimes 160px;  "CSS styles are applied immediately" nothing happens immediately in browser especially that concerns visual rendering there is such a thing as page reflow (https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) it takes time.  I think that the problem is there. I tied to speed up putting html on the page by prerendring and using innerHTML (before that I put documentFragment)- that enhanced the situation(lesser timeout)but I didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or the Google Chrome Dev tools? Right-clicking the problem area and choosing "Inspect Element" will display the code as it is after jQuery or any other Javascript has done its thing.

In order to see **how long** it takes (on your CPU, that is) for jQuery to do the desired actions you can keep the Google Chrome Dev tools code inspector open, refresh the page and hopefully see the code change or not change. This is the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out where the problem is, it was in dynamically applied page style (style tag created dynamically) though there is a timeout needed to wait after this style is added to the page. And some times position calculation still may fail if timeout is not enough. Not the most reliable strategy though -(